# How to change compiler on Clion from clang to gcc on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clion

The only compiler that works on my CLion is the clang one which is detected by default in toolchains. I need to use gcc (my college class grades using the gcc compiler so I want to avoid any unexpected issues) and have it installed through homebrew. In my terminal I can do g++ and gcc commands and it uses the right compiler, but I don't know how to change it in CLion. I must be doing something wrong with the location of it or the CMake settings. Any guidance would be appreciated and thank you. Let me know if there's any additional questions I can answer, my explanation may be insufficient as I am new to the world of CS. I see previous questions on how to switch compilers between gcc and clang, but not specifically on CLion.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Settings / Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake.
- [In the CMake options field, specify the compiler (**-D
  CMAKE__COMPILER=[fully qualified compiler name] )**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvpRR.png)

> The    **LANG** part specifies the language (C for C and CXX for C++),
> and you need to provide the full path to the compiler

- After you apply the settings, CLion will reset the CMake cache and
  reload your project.

Comment: If that comment is a correction to the answer,, you can make use of the [**Edit** link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68493724/edit) underneath the answer to make corrections and addition to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file > setting > build, execution > toolchains  and click on plus icon select the compiler you want.
clion will automatically detect the Environment, cmake and all things.
clike on apply.

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZk3f.png)